# How to get all weekends within a date range in C#

Tags: c#, .net, date-range, dayofweek, weekend

Is there a simple way or framework to get all weekends within a date range in C#?

Is it possible to do with [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) as well?

Comment: I suppose it's not too straightforward but it should be possible (including with LINQ). Good luck!

Comment: Superman, by now you should know that the answer to "is <x> possible" is almost always "yes". I suspect you want someone to show you how. You should ask that question instead if that's what you're seeking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found how to do it.

http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2011/06/finding-saturdaysunday-between-date.html

```
namespace DatimeApplication
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
             DateTime startDate=new DateTime(2011,3,1);
             DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;

             TimeSpan diff = endDate - startDate;
             int days = diff.Days;
             for (var i = 0; i <= days; i++)
             {
                 var testDate = startDate.AddDays(i);
                 switch (testDate.DayOfWeek)
                 {
                     case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                     case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                         Console.WriteLine(testDate.ToShortDateString());
                         break;
                 }
             }
           Console.ReadLine();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: The link is broken: *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at www.dotnetjalps.com."*. (The domain name [***isn't*** a misspelling](https://www.zoominfo.com/c/dotnetjalps/356919335).)

Answer (score 22):

If you make a way to enumerate all days, you can use LINQ to filter to weekends:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDaysBetween(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    for (DateTime i = start; i < end; i = i.AddDays(1))
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}

var weekends = GetDaysBetween(DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(365))
    .Where(d => d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

Comment: Wonder why this was downvoted, looks fine to me and while it's more power hungry than some of the other solutions (that avoid enumerating all days just to filter them) it is a very simple / clean / maintainable one on a problem that is unlikely to ever be a bottleneck unless the OP is working on thouthands of years periods. Upvoting to compensate.

Comment: [The Fastest Gun in the West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) shoot himself on the foot: It was downvoted (not by me) because when the answer was first posted it was badly formatted and incomplete. There are no revisions because Mitch fixed it fast enough to make SO not consider it a revision but not as fast for others to see it and downvote it

Comment: Yep, wasn't even trying to go quick... hit <kbd>tab</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> while I was still writing it.

Comment: @RonanThibaudau, this is actually something I have tested previously.  Despite the apparent decrease in performance you might imagine, I found that the naïve version actually outperformed the "smart" version in most tests.  Those tests were focusing on date modulus, so I can't say whether they would apply equally when using the `DayOfWeek` enumeration.  I do agree, however, that "programs should be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute."

Comment: @Mitch i was actually siding with that, the decrease in performance would be minor (with 5 additional calls to adddays per week vs none for the smart version), so it's possible to be made faster but we're talking extremely tiny amounts that wouldn't matter except in a tighy loop (i just wrote a quick specific version for weekends and tested it against yours, 100 times over 1000 years, your version is at 2700ms vs 600ms for mine, same results, but it still doesn't matter as most people don't try to get all weekends for the next 1000 years 100 times in a row)

Comment: This answer is mentioned in Stack Overflow blog post: [The next step in ecommerce? Replatform with APIs and micro frontends](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/12/12/the-next-step-in-ecommerce-replatform-with-apis-and-micro-frontends/)

Answer (score 1):

That's not really difficult to code... Here's an efficient iterator:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetWeekends(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    startDate = startDate.Date;
    endDate = endDate.Date;

    if (endDate < startDate)
        yield break;

    var currentDate = startDate;

    // Advance to next Saturday
    switch (currentDate.DayOfWeek)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
            break;

        case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
            yield return currentDate;
            currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(6);
            break;

        default:
            currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Saturday - currentDate.DayOfWeek);
            break;
    }

    while (currentDate <= endDate)
    {
        yield return currentDate;

        currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
        if (currentDate <= endDate)
            yield return currentDate;

        currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(6);
    }
}
```